# Setting value using base class functions from derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm new to c++. I'm trying to complete a c++ assignment involving Inheritance where the Car class must contain these methods setGarageSpaces function to set garage space to 2, and setNumWheels function to set wheels to 4.
I'm creating a no parameter constructor and inheriting from the base class Vehicle then using the set functions but I'm getting an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle();
  void setGarageSpaces(size_t spaces)
  {
      garage_spaces_ = spaces;
  }
  void setNumWheels(size_t wheels)
  {
      num_wheels_ = wheels;
  }

    Vehicle(std::string name, std::string manufacturer, double top_speed, double weight, double mpg, double curr_gas_amt);
  protected:
    size_t garage_spaces_;     // number of garage slots this vehicle takes up
    size_t num_wheels_;
};

class Car : public Vehicle {  //Car derived class inherits from base class Vehicle
public:
  Car(){  //no para constructor
    setGarageSpaces(2);
    setNumWheels(4);
  }
  
  Car(std::string name, std::string manufacturer, double top_speed, double weight, double mpg);

};

int main() {
  Car c;
  
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "I'm getting an error".

Comment: You need to implement Vehicle constructor. You can do that from c++ 11
```Vehicle() = default;```

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
    Vehicle();
```

Default Constructor for Vehicle is not implemented, you may want to do :

```
public:
    Vehicle() {}
```

When you expect proper construction, you can remove the default constructor from class, forcing user to impl. the proper constructor call.